# Error compiling a kernel module against Linux v5.4.0 (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm getting an error compiling a module from source obtained from here: https://github.com/JamesRHarris/infinitv_pcie.

I'm not sure if I have everything necessary installed to compile this module.  After a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 20.04.6, I installed gcc, make, and linux-headers-5.4.0-150-generic.  Executing

```sh
uname -r
```

gives me

```
5.4.0-150-generic
```

So I believe I have the right kernel headers installed. Anything else I'm missing?

Here is the error and the function where it occurs:

```
/home/robert/ceton-drivers/infinitv_pcie-master/ctn91xx_net.c: In function ‘ctn91xx_net_init’:
/home/robert/ceton-drivers/infinitv_pcie-master/ctn91xx_net.c:84:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘eth_hw_addr_set’; did you mean ‘eth_addr_dec’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   84 |     eth_hw_addr_set(netdev,addr);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |     eth_addr_dec
```

The function source is:

```c
int ctn91xx_net_init(ctn91xx_dev_t* dev)
{
    struct net_device *netdev = NULL;
    ctn91xx_net_priv_t *priv = NULL;
    u8 addr[6];
    int i;

    netdev = alloc_etherdev(sizeof(ctn91xx_net_priv_t));

    if (netdev == NULL) {
        ERROR("unable to alloc new ethernet");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

#if USE_PCI
    SET_NETDEV_DEV(netdev, &dev->pdev->dev);
#endif

    priv = netdev_priv(netdev);
    priv->ctn91xx_dev = dev;
    spin_lock_init(&priv->lock);

    snprintf(netdev->name, 20, "ctn%d", dev->board_number);

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,29)
    netdev->netdev_ops = &ctn91xx_net_device_ops;
#else
    netdev->open = ctn91xx_net_open;
    netdev->hard_start_xmit = ctn91xx_net_start_xmit;
    netdev->stop = ctn91xx_net_stop;
    netdev->get_stats = ctn91xx_net_get_stats;
    netdev->tx_timeout = ctn91xx_net_tx_timeout;
#endif
    netdev->watchdog_timeo = CTN91XX_NET_TX_TIMEOUT;

    i = register_netdev(netdev);
    if (i) {
        ERROR("failed to register netdev");
        free_netdev(netdev);
        return -EINVAL;
    }

#if USE_PCI
    addr[0] = 0x00;
    addr[1] = 0x22;
    addr[2] = 0x2c;
    addr[3] = 0xff;
    addr[4] = 0xff;
    addr[5] = 0xff - dev->board_number;
    eth_hw_addr_set(netdev,addr);
#else
    random_ether_addr(netdev->dev_addr);
#endif

    netdev->irq = dev->irq;
    netdev->base_addr = (unsigned long)dev->hw_reg_base;

    dev->net_dev = netdev;

#if USE_PCI
    ctn91xx_write8(1, dev->msg_base, MSG_BUFFER_INT_ENABLE);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

This function is in the "ctn91xx_pci.c" file which can be found at the GitHub link listed above. I know nothing about kernel programming so any help you have will be appreciated.

Comment: Just disable the warning noted in the error message by adding `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration` to `EXTRA_CFLAGS`. It seems the driver you want to build doesn't follow the strict rule "Every non-static definition should be accompanied with the declaration in a header file".

Comment: I added that declaration to the Makefile and now I'm getting this error:
`ERROR: "eth_hw_addr_set" [/home/robert/ceton-drivers/infinitv_pcie-master/ctn91xx.ko] undefined!`
It seems that it's not picking up the eth_hw_addr() function from either the kernel headers or some other include file.  Is there a development package that I still need to install?

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that the driver only calls given function but doesn't define it. The function `eth_hw_addr_set` has been introduced only in Linux kernel 5.15: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.116/A/ident/eth_hw_addr_set. May be, the driver misses some checks about the function's existence.

Comment: That function is easy to backport.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but adding the following code to the file somewhere above the `ctn91xx_net_init` function definition should help:

```c
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5,15,0)
static inline void eth_hw_addr_set(struct net_device *dev, const u8 *addr)
{
    memcpy(dev->dev_addr, addr, ETH_ALEN);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me compile the driver.  The tuner still doesn't seem to be operating correctly, although I'm not sure if that's a problem with the driver or if it's something in the Ubuntu Server 2020.04.6 OS that's preventing the tuner from responding properly to uPnP discovery requests.  Also, thanks to everyone who contributed information...it was helpful.